# C# Win. form - Convert String to DateTime

Tags: c#, string, winforms, date, datetime

I have multiple input in string like the following:-

1. 05/09/2017
2. 05/09/2017 13:56 PM
3. 05/09/2017 01:56 PM
4. 05/09/2017 13:56:00
5. 05/09/2017 01:56:00 PM

Now how do i convert the above examples into DateTime format (dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt).

### I have already tried

1. **ParseExact** - It gives error when the user gives **05/09/2017** as value (because the format doesn't match)

   `DateTime.ParseExact(ValueByuser, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", null);`
2. **TryParse** - The problem with it is that it uses the **LocalFormat** of the computer like if the computer has set to "MM/dd/yyyy" then it produces output in the same format

   `DateTime.TryParse(DatePass, out Dtp);`

Comment: Who in the world uses a 24 hour clock *and* an am/pm indicator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` overload that accepts an array of formats, and pass all the formats you want to support.  E.g.

```
var formats = new[]
{
    "dd/MM/yyyy",
    "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",
    "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm tt",
    "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
    "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",
};
```

You should also specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as your format provider, e.g.:

```
var d = DateTime.ParseExact(s, 
  formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

I believe the above will match all your sample inputs except the second (`05/09/2017 13:56 PM`) which I assume is a typo and should be `05/09/2017 13:56` without the am/pm indicator.

Comment: Agreed. Since the input format will not match any locale (it uses 24H clock with am/pm indicator which nobody in the world uses!) then the only solution is to explicitly list all supported formats individually.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like the following;

```
string dd = "05 / 09 / 2017 13:56:00";
string newdate = dd.Replace("/", "-");
DateTime DT = DateTime.Parse(newdate);
```